# First TreeViewItem not being styled (MahApps Metro TreeView)

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I'm using MahApps Metro Styling in WPF and trying to add a style to the TreeViewItem  so that the nodes have a folder icon next to them. (http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/)

This is fairly straight forward, all I have to do is override the TreeViewItem header template and add in the image.

The problem is that for some reason the new template is not applied to the first entry in the tree as you can see blow:

[image: TreeViewItem Style]

All other tree nodes work fine but the first one refuses to have the style applied.

I have confirmed that this is something to do with the MahApps TreeView styling contained in Controls.TreeView.xaml (a new project without MahApps but with the same custom style works as expected) but I cannot see exactly what is going on.

Does anyone have any experience styling TreeViewItems when using MahApps?

```
<TreeView Grid.Column="0" Name="FolderView">

        <TreeView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroTreeViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Name="img"
                                    Width="16"
                                    Height="16"
                                    Stretch="Fill"
                                    Source="Images/Folder.png"
                                    Margin="3"   
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
```

Comment: Instead of `DataTemplate`, try using `HierarchicalDataTemplate`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've tried the change but the results are the same.

Comment: Does the styling work on other items that contain children when expanded?

Comment: Yes, its just the MahApps treeview that seems to have this problem.. something to do with the template style they use.

Comment: @miked, Have You found any solution to this problem?

Comment: sorry no, I have not done any more work on the project and have not used the TreeView with MahApps since.

Answer (score 1):

try this`

```
<TreeView Grid.Column="0" Name="FolderView">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                            <Grid Background="Transparent">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="25" Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <ToggleButton x:Name="Expander"  IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ClickMode="Press">
                                    <ToggleButton.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                                        <Border Height="0" Width="0"/>
                                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </Style>
                                    </ToggleButton.Style>
                                </ToggleButton>
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header" ContentSource="Header"/>
                                <Grid x:Name="ItemsHost" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  Margin="0,-5,0,0">
                                    <ItemsPresenter />
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="false">
                                    <Setter TargetName="ItemsHost" Property="Visibility"  Value="Collapsed"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="HasItems"  Value="false">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Expander" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Name="img" Width="16" Height="16" Stretch="Fill" Source="Images/Folder.png" Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input but this also ignores the first entry in the tree. I think it is something to do with MahApps TreeView template rather than TreeViewItem

Answer (score 0):

**I've found the solution :**

You need to disable  MahApps Metro style like this : `Style="{x:Null}"`

```
<TreeView Style="{x:Null}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" >
<TreeView.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Width="20" Height="20" Stretch="Fill" Source="/Resources/folder.png" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```